# Why do I get 'ValueError: NaTType does not support strftime' even though it's not empty?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Forgive me if I am wrong, but AFAIK `ValueError: NaTType does not support strftime` will occur when the data is null or empty. But my data isn't.

Let's say I have this dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'personnel_number': ['123', '345', '567', '789', '000', '4444'],
                 'expiry_date': ['2020-12-07', '2099-12-04', '2019-08-30', '2022-03-19', '2020-09-06', '9999-12-31']})
```

And I want to convert it to date type format with the following code.

```
for exp_date in df['expiry_date']:
    date = pd.to_datetime(exp_date, errors='coerce').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print(date)
```

But I somehow always get this error when the looping reaches the last data (the '9999-12-31' date one).

```
ValueError: NaTType does not support strftime
```

I figured the year 9999 doesn't sound like it's making sense, but that's the data I have, I can't change it. So, what can I do?

Answer (score 13):

I think loop here is not necessary, use `pd.to_datetime` with column and then [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['expiry_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['expiry_date'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(df)
  personnel_number expiry_date
0              123  2020-12-07
1              345  2099-12-04
2              567  2019-08-30
3              789  2022-03-19
4              000  2020-09-06
5             4444         NaT
```

Reason for error is parameter `errors='coerce'` create missing values `NaT` for `'wrong'` datetimes, because here are out of limitation, [timestamp limitations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations):

```
In [92]: pd.Timestamp.min
Out[92]: Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')

In [93]: pd.Timestamp.max
Out[93]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But the fifth row isn't actually empty though. It has '9999-12-31' value. In your example, that value is replaced by `NaT`, which is not the value it's supposed to be.

Comment: I see. Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import pandas as pd

date = pd.to_datetime(exp_date, errors='coerce').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Also, you can do is:

```py
date = pd.to_datetime(exp_date, format ='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')
```